# Android Studio not working with HoloEverywhere and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I was able to import both ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere into Android Studio but I cannot get my app to compile.

screenshot:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwOn70drOiMfZHZVeXdEVzNXRXc/edit?usp=sharing

For whatever reason my intent's seem to be freaking out and even though the library imports seem to be working fine, I'm also getting the following errors trying to emulate my application:

```
java: /Users/patdugan/usmc-pro-fitness-abs-he/src/com/patdugan/usmcprofitness/USMCProFitMainActivity.java:16: package org.holoeverywhere.widget does not exist
```

Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: ohh its cool to see that you are using Android Studio.Can you share us your experience with android studio so far.

Comment: I think you should to see in File->Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies and add module dependencies

Comment: You were right @ADK. I had incorrectly added HE and ABS as libraries and although the dependencies were set correctly that's the reason it wasn't compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this issue.

What you need to do is go to `File > Project Structure...` and click on `Modules`. Make sure that ActionBarSherlock has the support library under its `Dependencies` tab. If not, click the plus at the bottom and add a Library (You may have to click `New Library...` to select the libs folder within the sub-project).

After this is done, change the scope to `Provided` so that you don't get lib conflicts when compiling your app.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Daniel. I tried making that change but still running into some problems: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwOn70drOiMfeW9XWC00T1k5WHM/edit. I think I'm close but I must be missing something, haha!

Comment: ActionBarSherlock needs to be included as its own Module, not as a library. Click the Plus icon and import the ActionBarSherlock module into the project.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Set HE and ABS as modules, added necessary dependencies to each one, and the project now compiles and runs as expected. You're the man @Daniel! Thank you!

Comment: @pdugan20 can you please zip your working project folder with HE and ABS and upload it? ive been trying to get HE working in Android Studio for days now

Answer (score 0):

Holoeverywhere doesn't use ActionBarSherlock anymore, it now relies on the ActionBarCompat library.