# App crashes when trying to extend SherlockActivity in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After importing the `actionbarsherlock` module, my app crashes on any activity that extends the `SherlockActivity`. I am not sure if I had imported it incorrectly or something needs to be adjusted but I have followed a guide that was previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591272/1671933) on stackoverflow. If i extend `Activity` and not `sherlockActivity` there will be no crash.
Guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591272/1671933
Logcat

```
05-24 08:41:46.072    1241-1241/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.sandbox.TestingCam
    at com.example.sandbox.LoginActivity$CheckLogin.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:204)
    at com.example.sandbox.LoginActivity$CheckLogin.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:155)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the link to the `Guide` that you have followed .  Did you build the entire project after importing the module and imparting it to your files ?

Comment: Did you directly copy the jar into `libs` folder and add it to the build path ?

Comment: No, I went through the importing module process, then setting actionbarsherlock as dependency in my project

Comment: I think , instead of that  you should just add it as a reference and have no physical existence in  your project set up . Twirl it here in this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443262/actionbarsherlock-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-actionbarsherlock-rstyle

Look at all the answers, any one of them might be a solution for you

Comment: You can also try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757400/setting-actionbarsherlock-theme-for-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the dependency scope is set to "compile". In some cases it seem to be set to "provided" which will cause a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Appreciate the help and advice, danke